# android:scheme must be set on the main activity or on the launch screen activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest, android-launcher

On with activity do i need to set the intent-filter connected to the android:scheme? on the launch screen activity or on the main activity?

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" />
      </intent-filter>
```

this are my 2 activity:

```
  <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">

      <intent-filter>  
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter> 

  </activity>


  <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
            android:label="%activityLabel%"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

      <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                 android:value="%libNameValue%" />

  </activity>
```

and this the code on my launch screen activity

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startActivity(new Intent(ScreenActivity.this, com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity.class));
    finish();
  }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Have you got any error (from java or gradle) or exception? We need more informations where you stucked.

Comment: normally scheme is added to the activity that you want to open via deeplink. its not specific to any activity, what is your actual requirement?